# Edits aren't being saved in Calibre

Tags: epub, editing

I've just spent the last two days taking all the bad line breaks and correcting type errors made in the conversion of my novel into an epub file. Up until an hour ago, my saves were taking. The file looked good.

I was on the home stretch and stopped for lunch. I hadn't closed the program and had carefully saved the files every five minutes or so. Now all my work is gone! The file looks terrible, as it did before I began editing.

Where did all that work go? I saved the files hundreds of times during the work on this editing job. Is Calibre broken? Should I do this tedious editing work in another program?

Answer (score 1):

For safest saving work with text in the text field, whether in special programs (Calibre, Sigil) or writing a simple post in a discussion or forum, it is good to copy this text`(ctrl + c)`and paste`(ctrl + v)`to notepad (or its equivalent according operating system) and save it separately.

(For example, [PSPad](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.5.8.html) or [Notepad++](http://www.pspad.com/en/) highlights special characters)

Comment: Before sending this answer, I put the text into the notepad and saved it. When anything fails. You still have a backup.